# How do you configure a FreeRadius system to enable pre-paid data?

Tags: php, mysql, database, radius

Typically a FreeRadius system contains a radacct table which keeps track of data in real time. Every hour or every day or each time the user logs off the current usage is added to the radacct table with the amount of data used and the date.

This makes it easy to offer post-paid data. In fact, you have to, because all that you can query is the data the client has used historically. But if you want to do pre-paid, I have thought about this for years and although I have come up with something that works similar to a bank, I am still not sure how to achieve pre-paid data. Once caveat is that pre-paid data might be valid for a few months, and since radacct works on the current date, I can't see how to achieve this.

I am looking for an easy way to enable an existing Radius system to allow pre-paid data without using any or too many stored procedures. I'm using MySQL and PHP.

Edit:
I revisited this post after a year and three months. We ended up using a product Radius Manager by DMA Softlab which has this functionality built-in. Doing this on our own would have required too many stored procedures and too much development time. Just explaining our architecture as requested by @maraspin is a mission.

Comment: Can you please describe your architecture? What radius vendor do you rely upon (openradius)? What are all the entities involved in your infrastructure? I've worked on a project where what you're talking about was implemented, but I need more info about your situation to be able to try providing some help.

Comment: What problem do you have with stored procedures? But nice you found a solution. :-)